# Meaning of "on the practical level,"

Tags: american-english, british-english

Can you please explain the meaning of "on the practical level" in below context?

This matters not just because of the inhumanity and distress but on the practical level,

Source of info: https://youtu.be/JEaX_F6VJLE?t=281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And this matters not just because of the inhumanity and distress, but on **a** practical level, it tells where to allocate resources..."

When she says "on a practical level", she is referring to what she goes on to say after that. You could substitute that phrase with "pragmatically" and it would mean the same thing. Look into what pragmatic means to get a better understanding.

What is going on here is that she starts by pointing out that this is important in an emotional/justice kind of way, but then goes on to point out other more concrete reasons as to why it is important, whence it being "on a practical level" as opposed to something that is more emotional or abstract, such as the things she stated prior.

I hope this cleared things up for you.